# Why are commas not allowed in a username when using the SqlMembershipProvider?

Tags: validation, sqlmembershipprovider, argumentexception, createuser

Although **NOT** documented as a part of the [CreateUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.createuser.aspx) method on MSDN, the SqlMembershipProvider throws an ArgumentException if you try to do anything with a username containing a comma (including trying to create a user). Commas in passwords appear to be ok.  My question is why?

```
System.ArgumentException: The parameter 'username' must not contain commas.
```

**Edit:** As documented on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109605/the-parameter-username-must-not-contain-commas-parameter-name-username), one such reason for allowing commas would be that, while unusual, e-mail addresses **CAN** contain commas.

Comment: Perhaps the better question is "Why do you want to use commas in usernames?".

Comment: No particular reason.  I just find it curious that other punctuation is allowed.  Does allowing commas pose a security risk of some kind that I should be aware of?

Comment: No security issue that I know of; its just a very strange requirement.

Comment: I updated the question to indicate one possible reason for allowing commas.

Comment: I you really want to use commas, you could implement your own `MembershipProvider`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  At this point I don't think it's worth the cost.  I'll stick with the SqlMembershipProvider.

Answer (score 1):

My bet is the passwords are hashed and the usernames are not. I have no backup on this, however. Just imagine you wanted to concatenate user input into a string and several fields are spearated by commas. Wouldn't it be easier for you to just resrict commas rather than find a ridiculous way to escape and/or encode a comma in the middle of the string?

EDIT: Actually, in the [UpdateUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.updateuser.aspx) method, it is documented that a user name cannot contain a comma. They still don't explain why there is a restriction, however. This is from the section on when an ArgumentException is thrown:

> The UserName property of user is an empty string (""), contains a
>   comma, or is longer than 256 characters.